# Python: BeautifulSoup get.tag to table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

I've got another problem in my code:

```
for tag in bs.find_all('a'):
   print(tag.get('rel')[0])
   print(tag.get('title'))
```

Is printing values correctly, but how to get the output into the table?

It must look something like this: `{None: {"rel"}, "title": {"rel1", "rel2"}}` etc...

Comment: Can you precise your question please ?

Comment: @glegoux I'm trying to save variables from "tag.get" to dict

Comment: `{tag.get('rel')[0] : tag.get('title') for tag in self.loadtree_parser.find_all('a')}` roughly, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here your solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict

html = """
<a href="page1.html" title="1" rel="nofollow">link1</a>
<a href="page2.html" title="2" rel="author">link2</a>
<a href="page3.html" title="1">link3</a>
<a href="page4.html" title="3" rel="nofollow">link4</a>
<a href="page5.html" title="3" rel="bookmark">link5</a>
<a href="page6.html" title="1" rel="nofollow bookmark">link6</a>
<a href="page7.html" title="1" rel="">link7</a>
<a href="page8.html" title="1">link8</a>
<a href="page9.html" rel="unfollow">link9</a>
<a href="page10.html">link10</a>
"""

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

table = defaultdict(set)
for tag in bs.find_all('a'):
    title = tag.get('title')
    rel = tag.get('rel')
    rel = rel if rel else [None]
    table[title] = table[title].union(set(rel))
print(table)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {
    '1': {'bookmark', '', None, 'nofollow'}, 
    None: {'unfollow', None}, 
    '3': {'bookmark', 'nofollow'},
    '2': {'author'}
})
```